# How to fix UnicodeEncodeError: in Pyspark while converting Dataframe Row to a String

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a simple dataframe with 3 columns.

```
+------------------+-------------------+-------+
|       NM1_PROFILE|  CURRENT_DATEVALUE|     ID|
+------------------+-------------------+-------+
|XY_12345678 – Main|2019-12-19 00:00:00|myuser1|
+------------------+-------------------+-------+
```

All i want in the output is a single string consists of all the values in dataframe row separated by comma or pipe. Although there are many rows in the dataframe, i just want 1 row to solve my purpose.

```
XY_12345678 – Main,2019-12-19 00:00:00,myuser1
```

I have tried with below and it has worked fine for my other dataframes but for above it gives me an error.

```
df.rdd.map(lambda line: ",".join([str(x) for x in line])).take(1)[0]
```

Error when it encounters "-"

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)

I am using Spark 1.6 with Python 2 and tried -

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: Hi ! Did you try with concat_ws built-in function ? https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws

Answer (score 0):

According to the Spark 1.6 Documentation, you can use the concat_ws function, which  giving a separator and a set of columns, it will concat them in one string. So this should solve your issue

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws
df.select(concat_ws(",", col("NM1_PROFILE"), col("CURRENT_DATEVALUE"), col("ID")).alias("concat")).collect()
```

Or, if you prefer a more generic way, you can use something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws
cols = [col(column) for column in df.columns]
df.select(concat_ws(",", *cols).alias("concat")).collect()
```

For more information: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws

Hope this helps